# Heroku Node.js Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, heroku

I found a dozen solutions for Express powered apps with setting port to listen on.
But I have an app that doesn't use Express and doesn't in fact listens anything.
And after 60 seconds of it successfully running I get a `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch` message.
How I can get around it? Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After lots of googling I decided to `npm install express` and add

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

//For avoidong Heroku $PORT error
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    var result = 'App is running'
    response.send(result);
}).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('App is running, server is listening on port ', app.get('port'));
});
```

This fixed the error, even though I don't like adding express just to avoid one error. If someone finds a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the best solution here, but one thing I know (that did work) was to use Node.js built-in module `http` instead of requiring express module. ```var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.send('it is running\n');
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 5000); ```

Comment: Look at the answer below about changing your procfile and scaling your dynos by @pille. It is much better than this answer as it is not a workaround but the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 35):

If your app doesn't listen any port then you should use another type of app in you Procfile, I mean in Procfile you have:

```
web: node app.js
```

replace it with:

```
worker: node app.js
```

"web" type of application means that your app MUST listen some port

Comment: As it seems, Heroku seems to ignore the settings in the Procfile.

Comment: @Pille, have you installed [node-foreman](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman)?

Comment: In my case it was `worker: npm start`, but the idea remains the same. It worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 24):

Another way would be changing the dynos from web (standard setting regardless of the settings in Procfile) to worker with these commands:

```
heroku ps:scale web=0
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Sometimes Heroku ignores settings in the Procfile.

Comment: The second command failed for me. I had to set up `worker: npm start` in my Procfile first.

Comment: This worked for me, well it didn't to begin with until I removed the heroku ps:scale web=0 line, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This comment solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67787556/8684435

The issue is the way you define the port, it always runs on 3001 which is not possible on Heroku, you need to bind the $PORT env variable.
Change your code to check the first fi the process.env.PORT is defined (it will be on Heroku but on your local dev environment it will default to 3001)

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log("Server is running.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

I tried many things.

The following works without using express:

```
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(process.env.PORT || 6000)
```

Comment: where do i need to set that line?

Comment: I have the same issue, but I use AdonisJS and I can't edit this line...

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same  the same problem:
`Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

flowing work in my pc windows 10 visual studio code

`app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);`

also added these three line in `package.json`

`"worker": "node index.js",`
`"start": "node index.js"`
`"test": "node test.js"`