# Run Bitgo's Express service on Heroku - Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds

Tags: node.js, heroku

It is the first time I do something like this. Any pointers or tips to the right direction will greatly help.

I am trying to run this [Bitgo's service](https://platform.bitgo.com/blog/post/bitgo-express-quickstart) on Heroku. I followed Heroku's tutorial and pushed the app.

This app is not a web app. It is a service receiving requests. I am wondering how I will run it to receive this requests on Heroku.

I created a "[Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)" and wrote the following line in it:

`web: ./bin/bitgo-express`

Then when I check the logs (without doing or trying anything at all) I get the following errors and logs:

```
2016-06-16T08:22:35.353721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-16T08:22:37.366281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./bin/bitgo-express`
2016-06-16T08:22:40.433443+00:00 app[web.1]: BitGo-Express running
2016-06-16T08:22:40.434385+00:00 app[web.1]: Environment: test
2016-06-16T08:22:40.434540+00:00 app[web.1]: Base URI: http://localhost:3080
2016-06-16T08:23:37.991458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-06-16T08:23:37.991458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-06-16T08:23:38.795553+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-06-16T08:23:38.810670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-06-16T08:23:41.439218+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=example.com request_id=a42a1654-2593-499c-81fa-a585464b2805 fwd="109.110.240.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-06-16T08:23:42.964194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=example.com request_id=008620c3-b40f-43c1-add3-e3f8b785d5c5 fwd="109.110.240.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

A note. When I run this service locally it opens a website that redirects to a bitgo's website but I am also able to execute commands and work with the service.

I googled the error and tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693371/2911232) which proposes to change the listening port but I was still getting the same behaviour. Just to clarify on the [bitgo app](http://github.com/BitGo/bitgo-express) I changed all 3080 ports to 5000 that Heroku uses.

I then tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36604249/2911232) which proposes to change the "web" process to "worker" but I was getting errors that they seem to be generated because of the reason that the service was not structured as a worker process (maybe, that is what I think) but web process.

And lastly, I changed the procfile's text to `web: ./bin/bitgo-express -p 3080` so it runs at the 3080 port but I was still getting the same error

Edit: 
I have `web: ./bin/bitgo-express -p 5000 -b 0.0.0.0` in my procfile.

Again, same result. Here are the logs:

```
2016-06-20T06:17:36.753762+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./bin/bitgo-express -p 5000 -b 0.0.0.0`
2016-06-20T06:17:39.333304+00:00 app[web.1]: BitGo-Express running
2016-06-20T06:17:39.334368+00:00 app[web.1]: Environment: test
2016-06-20T06:17:39.334384+00:00 app[web.1]: Base URI: http://0.0.0.0:5000
2016-06-20T06:18:36.768622+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-06-20T06:18:36.768550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Comment: Did you have any success in solving your problem?

Comment: @AndreyKryachkov no sorry. Heroku's support gave up on me and blamed bitgo. I instead used a Digital Ocean droplet that works perfectly now.

Comment: thank you, Stefanos

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify `-b` or `--bind` as `0.0.0.0` in your Profile. Otherwise, it will try to bind to localhost, which cannot be reached from Heroku's routing tier.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried it and getting the same error. Edited question and added the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$PORT` environment variable provided by Heroku on your `Procfile`, i.e rails application: `web: bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`

For BitGo you can configure like that: **`web: ./bin/bitgo-express -p $PORT -b 0.0.0.0`**